# Resolution of an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Did exists a method to find a resolution of singularities of an
affine algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ such that its resolution is 
affine too?

Comment: By definition, a resolution is proper and birational to the original variety. So if an affine resolution exists, then the resolution map is finite and birational, thus is equal to the normalization. In summary, an affine resolution exists if and only if the normalization already gives a smooth variety.